# SharePoint 2010 workflow fail to run after pause

Tags: 2010, sharepoint-designer, sharepoint-foundation, designer-workflow, pause

Situation:
A Custom List and a approval workflow designed by SharePoint Designer 2010

The approval workflow will pause 5 mins when the item created , after pause, will start the approval process.

When only one item into the custom list ,after pause 5 mins ,  it will randomly to show the error 'xxx workfow fail to run'.

When more then one item created into the list , after pause 5 mins , it will randomly to show error ' xxx workflow fail to run' on each items , sometime only show the error on one item.

Work around:
I try to modifiy the pause action longer , e.g.  pause 5 mins updated to pause 1 hour.
And not allow the worklfows run at same time.

e.g.

workflow a:12:30

workflow b:01:45

workflow c:02:00

I would like to know , how can I fix the 'xxx workfow fail to run' error

Thanks.

---

2014-06-17
In this case ,
I start the workflow at 10:06 am , and workflow pause 30mins , after pause activity done , it show error workflow fail to run.
[image]

Comment: What is the first activity in your workflow?

Comment: To Aanchal: Pause until xxx is the first activity

Comment: After pause what is next?

Comment: Send Email to someone

Answer (score 1):

I've run into the same issue recently and came across the following MS support article: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2674684

This is assuming you're running the workflow timer on multiple servers and one of those doesn't have the web application service running.